Как скопировать гугл таблицу вместе с скриптом и тригером к нему?
Для работы, приходится постоянно делать на каждый новый проект, копию таблицы, которая является образцом. В этой таблице есть скрипты и есть тригеры. Так вот при создании копии, копируется таблица с скриптом, а вот тригер, приходится прописывать по новой. И так к каждой из 20-50 копий в день. Как можно скопировать таблицу так, что бы и тригер тоже скопировался?

https://stackoverflow-com.translate.goog/questions/49990035/how-to-copy-a-google-sheet-and-keep-its-project-triggers-and-scripts?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=ru&_x_tr_hl=ru&_x_tr_pto=sc
тут есть ответ
